# Mod Rewrite Rule Rewrite Cond with if then else

Tags: mod-rewrite

can some one help with the Modrewrite Cond.

expected behavior is to search for a file in a directory and if found, simply serve that file otherwise if not found redirect to a different host#2 with the same path.
If it is not found in host#2 with the same path as well redirect to host#3 with same path

For example, user requests for 6 files via `server1/ecms/test-redirect/1.gif` and `server1/ecms/test-redirect/2.gif` etc until `server1/ecms/test-redirect/6.gif`

search for files first in `server1/ecms/test-redirect/`

found 3 files in here - serve them

3 files not found in here

then search for the 3 files in `server2/ecms/test-redirect/`
found 2 files here
1 file not foun here

then search for 1 file in server3/ecms/test-redirect

Comment: Does server 1 and 2 and 3 all point to the same site? Otherwise this isn't so much if-then-else, it's rules on 2 servers

Comment: Thanks Jon. To provide more clarity, akamai comes to my site xyz and first i need to search on my primary webservers first for content and server but if not found there, search other servers and serve etc.

Comment: Thanks Jon. To provide more clarity, akamai comes to my site xyz and first i need to search on my primary webservers first for content and server but if not found there, search other servers and serve etc. Also, it can be applied to the directories as well within the same server. I am wondering a powerful tool like mod rewrite cannot allow this kind of scripting bothering me!